# How to fix 'cannot read property subscribe' of undefined during angular unit testing?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Angular6 - Unit testing error “Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined”

I was writing a unit test for an angular component which is having several dependencies. One of those dependent service has some properties as observables. I tried to mock this service but is throwing error as in title,

spec.ts

```
describe('Component', () => {
let mockService= jasmine.createSpyObj(['property1', 'property2', 'property3']);

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
declarations: [testComponent],
providers: [
......someOther,
{ provide service, useValue: mockService},
......someOther
]
}).compileComponents();

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(testComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
}));

it('should be created', () => {
expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

ts file has

```
this.Service.property1.subscribe(() => {})
this.Service.property2.subscribe(() => {})
this.Service.property3.subscribe(() => {})
```

Expect test case to pass but fails with error as in title

Comment: the mock service that you have created does it have same keys as actual one?

Comment: yeah, I cant share the actual code but it is similar to as above

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a spy in this way try to create spy in

> then

block of

> compileComponents

Like this

```
let service:Service

.compileComponents().then(()=>{

  spyOn(service:Service, 'any method / property').and.returnValue(Observable.of(MOCKDATA));

)}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: please check what does it print in console for service via console.log